# Perform only validation of record (without creating it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model which implements some validation. Is it possible to only do a validation without creating an object?

Edit: The reason why I would need is the following. I need to create two records in a given order, but I have to validate in advance, if the second record would be invalid. If so, it's not allowed to create the first record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just call `valid?` on the object:

```
user = User.new
user.valid? #=> false
user.errors #=> 'name missing...'
```

Answer (score 2):

Without even initializing an object? No. Without persisting the object to the database? Yes. Use [`valid?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/valid%3F) to check if it's valid, then use [`errors`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveModel/Validations/errors) if you want to know which validation(s) failed.

```
my_obj = MyModel.new(some_attr: "some_value")

unless my_obj.valid?
  puts "There were errors!"
  p my_obj.errors
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`@model.valid?` will return true if valid, and false if not. If there are failing validations, `@model.errors` will say why